# How can I access my personal data through the Evernote API?

Tags: evernote

I would like to make some Pyton or NodeJS script to help me with repetitive tasks or searchs in my personal Evernote.

I don't want to make any application for general use. Only some scripts for me.

Is there a quick way to make this before creating an account in sandbox.evernote.com? I want to access my already available data in Evernote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this exact thing exists. Go here:
https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/dev_tokens.php

And get a "developer token" for your production account. It will allow access to your account only and you can do what you like with your data via the API.